# Prove that $x \rightarrow \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-tx}}{1+e^{-t}}dt$ is convex

Tags: integration, inequality, convex-analysis

**To put it bluntly I'm stuck proving proving the subsequent inequality**

$$ \forall x>0, \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-tx}}{1+e^{-t}}dt \int_0^\infty \frac{t^2 e^{-tx}}{1+e^{-t}}dt \geq {\left ( \int_0^\infty \frac{te^{-tx}}{1+e^{-t}}dt \right )}^2$$

**Some context**

Let's define the following function $f$ on $\mathbb R^+_*$: $$f(x)=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-tx}}{1+e^{-t}}dt$$

$f$ looks like this

[image: It looks like this:]

Now I need to prove that $ln(f)$ is convex.

Using the inequality-based definition of convexity is a deadend.

Assessing the sign of $ln(f)^{(2)}$ seems more reasonible : $$ln(f)^{(2)}=\frac{f''f-f'^2}{f^2}$$

which boils down to proving that $f''f-f'^2$ is positive.

The inequality $f''f-f'^2 \geq 0 $ looks really sharp! (see picture)[image]

Therefore I have to prove that:

$$ \forall x>0, \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-tx}}{1+e^{-t}}dt \int_0^\infty \frac{t^2 e^{-tx}}{1+e^{-t}}dt \geq {\left ( \int_0^\infty \frac{te^{-tx}}{1+e^{-t}}dt \right )}^2$$

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks silly to answer one's own question a few minutes after it's been published, but anyway...

It suffices to apply the Cauchy Schwarz inequality for integrals which states that for any functions $u,v$
$$\displaystyle \left({\int_a^b u \left({t}\right) v \left({t}\right) \ \mathrm d t}\right)^2 \le \int_a^b \left({u \left({t}\right)}\right)^2 \mathrm d t \int_a^b \left({v \left({t}\right)}\right)^2 \mathrm d t$$

with $u(t)=\sqrt {\frac{e^{-tx}}{1+e^{-t}}}$ and $v(t) =t\sqrt {\frac{e^{-tx}}{1+e^{-t}}}$

Comment: That, or the fact that the variance of a random variable with a well chosen distribution on $(0,+\infty)$ is positive.